# Регистрация с ajax

Tags: javascript, php

**Информация:**
Делаю регистрацию с ajax,

**Возникшие вопросы:**

1. Есть ли в `JS` альтернатива `php`-ному

   ```
   if(empty($password) or empty($name) or empty($mail)){
   }
   else{
   }
   ```
2. Не глупо ли делать не `post`, а `get`

   ```
   http.open('get', 'reg.php?email='+email+'&psw='+password);
   http.onreadystatechange = regReply;
   http.send(null);
   ```
3. Как получить обратный ответ с `reg.php`.

Answer (score 4):

1) Сделайте свою функцию

```
function empty(val){
    return val == null || val === '';
}
```

2) Глупо, подделать GET намного проще, чем POST

3) Получить ответ:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    alert(xhr.responseText);
  }
}
xhr.open('GET', 'http://example.com', true);
xhr.send(null);
```

Comment: Ну, а если передавать  например зашифрованные ip

Comment: Шифровать :] Но? как ? RSA?

Comment: Причём здесь IP? Зачем их вообще использовать при регистрации? Основной минус GET-запроса: всё, что вы передаёте, высвечивается в адресной строке. Ещё непонятно, зачем что-то шифровать на стороне клиента. Клиент в любом случае смодет это расшифровать. А если боитесь хакеров, перехватывающих запросы, используйте SSL, это гораздо надёжнее.

Answer (score 3):

1. Аналога нет, но [реализовать свой не трудно](http://phpjs.org/functions/empty/)
2. Глупо
3. В функции regReply (читаем [любую статью про AJAX](http://javascript.ru/ajax/intro#chto-takoe-ajax-primer-realizacii))

Answer (score 0):

Для примера реализации, с полученными данными делать можно все что захочешь, в данном случае они просто алертом выводятся.
JQuery + AjaxForms зачем изобретать вилосипед заного?
https://bitbucket.org/avengerweb/register/src